# AJAX - unexpected token < in JSON doesn't call complete function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call for saving a record on one of my pages. On button click, I have a processing image shown up and on complete, the image should be hidden. But, if by any chance there is an error occurring on the server side, an error saying `unexpected token < in JSON` is printed in the browser's console and the completed method is not being called. This is my AJAX call :

```
jQuery('body').on('click', "#save, function(e) {
    jQuery("processing").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url : "userEdit/save.do",
        data: {         
            "userId" : row.id
        }
    })
    .success(function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    })
    .complete(function () {
        jQuery("processing").hide();
    })
    .error(function () {
        jQuery("processing").hide();
    });
});
```

This is making the user feel that the process is taking for ever to complete. Is there a way to hide the processing image even if an AJAX call is completed with errors? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error means you're getting a HTML or XML response, not a JSON one - likely due to an error raised on the server. Check the actual responseText in the console to see what the response is

Comment: He knows. He is asking how to always hide the throbber

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RoryMcCrossan , mplungjan. As mplungjan said, I am not really concerned about either what the error on the server side is or what the response is. I am only concerned about the processing image not being hidden after the AJAX call is completed!

Comment: Why not just make a setTimeout for jQuery("processing").hide() with 5 seconds before the call? (although the best would be to treat the error server side and through a proper error code instead)

Comment: I think the `.error()` code should get called when this happens, which should hide the processing image.

Comment: @Barmar nope, it is not being called

Comment: There's a missing `"` after `#save`. Are you sure you copied the code accurately into the question?